# Command to copy current time and date to clipboard in Windows 7

Tags: clipboard, piping, windows-console

In Windows 7 command prompt, I needed a command to copy current date and time to the clipboard. I used

```
time /t & date /t | clip
```

but it only copies the date and not the time. What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo %date%%time% | clip
```

result: Mon 03/28/2016 8:34:29.34

Comment: On windows 10, this produced the output `08-Feb-1923:30:39.07`.  Adding a space between `%date%` and `%time%` fixed it. Exact output may depend on the region settings.

Answer (score 0):

time /t > timeanddate.txt
date /t >> timeanddate.txt
type timeanddate.txt | clip
11:14 PM
Mon 07/30/2018